# Problem of FileEncoding of the output file of FileTemplateApply

Tags: files-and-directories, templates

Problem of FileTemplateApply

FileTemplateApply will change a file-encoding[UTF8] into a file-encoding[WindowsANSI], it seems it doen't accept `CharacterEncoding` Option.

I'm on Windows@Mathematica 10.2

```
FileTemplateApply[File@"t1.txt","","t2.txt"]
```

[image]

Comment: I took a quick look at the docs for `FileTemplateApply`, but I found no direct mention of file encoding, so I am not sure what you are referring to. Could you expand on your intended goal, and on the problem you are facing? It would be best if you could include any code you are using, together with a relevant example.

Comment: @MarcoB You can open a .txt file and change it's file encoding, MS-notepad, save as ,UTF8, WindowsANSI, Unicode, and so on...  Or notepad++ or other IDE/Editor to change File encoding to , UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Can you include your code that uses `FileTemplateApply` so we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @MarcoB see edit